# Excel cell autoformatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to type the name "True" in a cell and it keeps turning it into a function "TRUE" and I cannot turn off the autoformatting no matter what I try. Help!

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way to force Excel to treat an entry as text is to start with an apostrophe so try entering:

'True

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  I have found that when I clear the formulas or delete the commands from the whole page, I can manually customize the cells as I go along, if I need to.  I just click on the small square in the top left corner of cell A1, under the formula bar, where the columns & rows meet.  It should highlight the whole page except for cell A1.  Right click anywhere on the page to bring up options.  Select *clear contents* to erase all existing data.  The page will still be highlighted once the data disappears, so right click again to bring the options back up.  Here, I selected *format cells* & choose *Text* under the *Number* Tab, (there are a some other tabs).  Now I can type anything anywhere (numbers, letters, characters or a combination) & it stays just like I want it.  Good luck with your journey to finding the information you need.  I wish you a fulfilling and speedy resolve.